# Complex Analysis: using the definition of a limit to prove continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove, using the definition of a limit, that the function is continuous everywhere

$$f(z) = \bar z $$
$f:S$ $\subset C \to C$

$$Assuming |z - a| < \delta$$ how to prove $$|\bar z - \bar a| <  \varepsilon$$
where $z,a \in C$

I attempted to use the triangle inequality that $$|z - a| <= |z| + |a|$$
and 
$$|\bar z - \bar a| <= |z| + |a|$$ 
then taking $ |z| + |a| < \delta = \varepsilon$    but then realised that |z| + |a| takes a minimum at |a| and wouldn't be a valid proof because the proof requires any $\varepsilon > 0$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? As a whole, the community here frowns heavily on just answering what appear to be homework questions without evidence of effort. If you've already tried some things, go ahead and include those in the question.

Comment: Tips on MathJax: "\bar z" gives $\bar z$, or "\overline z" as $\overline z$; the arrow is available as "\to" , like $\to$. Also, what have you tried? Please add your attempt in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

To prove continuity, we fixed an $\epsilon > 0$,

Now, we have to pick $\delta >0$ such that if $|z-a| < \delta$ then we must have $|\bar{z} - \bar{a}| < \epsilon$.

- But remember that $|\bar{z}-\bar{a}|=|z-a|$.

So the task now is:

We have to pick $\delta >0$ such that if $|z-a| < \delta$ then we must have $|\bar{z} - \bar{a}|=|z-a| < \epsilon$.

Can you see how to pick $\delta$ now?